# Sign .net Core Debug Build in Visual Studio Code

Tags: .net, wpf, visual-studio, console-application, code-signing

due to group policy we are not able to debug our .net applications whatsoever.

[image]

what we did as a solution for releases is to create a code signin certificate.
this works perfectly fine for release buidls and published versions of our applications.

tha major problem we have tough is that we are also not able to debug in Visual Studio (screenshot below)

what i did so far:

- create publish for productive releases which are signed (ClickOnce) -> works for published version
- add strong naming (proj settings -> build -> strong naming) -> not working for debug version which is generated under (bin/Debug)
- i checked both versions with powershell using `Get-AppLockerFileInformation <path/to/exe>` -> published version has a publsher there, debug version doesnt

so my question now is am I missing something?
is it even possible to sign the Debug version?
or do we have to have a location "allowed" by group policy where we can execute the unsigned Debug version?

thanks and BR,
Albert